# Prove that $\{x\} \times B \in R^{n} \times R^{m} $ is compact, when $B \in R^{m} $ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove that $\{x\} \times B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{n} \times \Bbb{R}^{m} $ is compact, when $B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{m} $ is compact.

My attempt:
Let $\{x\} \times B \subset \cup G_{a} $, where $\cup G_{a} = \cup G_{a1} \times \cup G_{a2}$ such that $\{x\} \subset \cup G_{a1}$ and $B \subset \cup G_{a2}$. $( G_{a}  , G_{a1} $ and $G_{a2}  
$
are open sets.$) $

So there exists an open set such that  $\{x\} \subset O_{a1} \subset \cup G_{a1}$ and a finite open cover of $B$ such that $ B \subset \bigcup_{a2=1}^{n} G_{a2} \subset
\cup G_{a2}$

This implies $\{x\} \times B \subset O_{a1} \times \bigcup_{a2=1}^{n} G_{a2}$

So, $\{x\} \times B$ is compact.
Is this proof correct$? $
If it's not right then please help me out with right one using the definition of compact set (without using heine borel theorem.)

Comment: What if there are no open sets $\Omega_1\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and $\Omega_2\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} G_i=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every open set of $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$ is of the form $U\times V$, with $U\subseteq \Bbb R^m$, $V\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ open. Take for example the interior of the unit ball $B(1,0)\subseteq \Bbb R^2$. I understand your definition of your cover in that way...

Yet, it is the right idea. As the open sets of the form $U \times V$ form a basis of the topology on $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$, if we are given a cover
$$X \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{i \in I} W_i \;\;\;(1)$$
of a subspace $X \subseteq \Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$, we immediately obtain another cover
$$X\subseteq \bigcup \limits_{i \in I} \bigcup \limits_{j \in J_i} U_{ij}\times V_{ij}\;\;\;(2)$$
writing the opens $W_i$ with respect to the basis.

Now assume that $X = \{x\} \times K$ for some $x\in \Bbb R^m$ and compact $K \subseteq \Bbb R^n$. Then the cover (2) yields an open cover
$$K \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{i \in I, j \in J_i} V_{ij}.$$
By compactness of $K$ finitely many $V_{ij}$ suffice, with pairs of indices denoted  $i_1j_1,...,i_kj_k$. Note that every $U_{ij}$ has to contain $\{x\}$. Hence we find
$$\{x\}\times K \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{t=1}^k U_{i_tj_t}\times V_{i_tj_t} \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{t=1}^k W_{i_t}$$
which is a finite subcover of our original cover (1).

Comment: Are cover (1) and (2) equivalent$?$

Comment: Equivalent in what sense? The sets $\bigcup W_i$ and $\bigcup \bigcup U_{ij}\times V_{ij}$ are the same, but (2) is not a refinement of (1) in that it doesn’t contain the sets $W_i$. What matters is that a finite subcover of (2) yields a finite subcover of (1), which is what compactness asks us to show

Comment: Okay, so it's from topology, that ever open set $U$ in $X$, $(X$ is a set $) $ can be expressed as a union of basis elements. So, here you've expressed the open cover as a union of open rectangles. Am I right$? $

Comment: Sorry for answering late. Exactly, you will have to use some information about the topology on the product, in this case that every open $W$ can be expressed as a union of basic opens $\bigcup_i U_i \times V_i$